# Should I have used "is" or "are" when telling a friend "Jennifer and Amy is going"?

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

Its all in the title. I messaged a friend on Facebook the other day. I told him "Jennifer and Amy is Going" Should I have used are or is?

Answer (score 1):

The subject is plural so the correct usage is "Jennifer and Amy are going".  The verb applies to entire subject, not just part of it.

Comment: Wayne you is right!  ;-)